# Navigating the UI to unique keyword(string, paragraph) in MS Word document using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, office-js-ux

I'm receiving the string with preferred location from backend to achieve uniqueness. Please help me out with this using word API. Using this approach, i am able to search doc, but result is not unique and UI is also not navigating to the keyword.

```
export let FilterSearchDoc = (e, key, string) => {
    console.log("key pressed", key, string.string, string);
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var searchResults = context.document.body.search(string.string, { ignorePunct: true });
        context.load(searchResults, 'font');
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            console.log('Found count: ' + searchResults.items.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
                searchResults.items[i].font.color = 'black';
                searchResults.items[i].font.highlightColor = '#FFFF00'; //Yellow
                searchResults.items[i].font.bold = false;
            }
            return context.sync();
        });
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
}
```